# PayPal IPN SHA-256 server requirement

Tags: ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn, centos6, sha

To begin with, I already posted the same question in serverfault.com and received no help, so I'm repeating it here out of desperation.

Recently PayPal is requiring servers to support SHA-256. Here's an article referring to this issue:

https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US

At the top of the article, it states,

> Update your integration to support certificates using the SHA-256 algorithm. PayPal is upgrading SSL certificates on all Live and Sandbox endpoints from SHA-1 to the stronger and more robust SHA-256 algorithm.

We have a dedicated CentOS server with numerous sites, mostly WordPress. Quite a few use PayPal IPN but do not have dedicated IPs or SSL Certificates. What needs to be changed to the server so these sites will support SHA-256? Our server is situated with Limestone Networks so I've created a ticket and asked repeatedly for assistance to no avail. They keep repeating SSL's need to be updated on the server. Would that be a wildcase SSL certificate in the usage case I described? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your existing certificate is SHA1, just contact your certificate provider to reissue it. There should be no charge for this service, if you have a decent certificate provider.

Comment: miken32, I wish it were that simple. The server has WHM/cPanel, and when I check the domain name used to login to WHM with `https://shachecker.com` it shows that 'name.domain.com has a verifiable certificate chain signed with SHA-2.' The problem is with all the client accounts hosted on the server, the one's that don't have their own SSL certificates. That's why I mentioned 'wildcard SSL', in case that's what gets used for those accounts

Comment: That link you provided is about Paypal's site changing *their certificate* to SHA-256.

Comment: See [this discussion](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/6369/do-sites-without-ssl-now-need-one-for-paypal-ipn) regarding clarity (re: _IF_ you do SSL) - you could also contact PayPal directly to obtain official answers....

Comment: EdSF, thanks for the article link. It's informative but I still don't know how to fix the problem. The server has OpenSSL version 1.0.1e-fips, which should support SHA-256 & I have created self-signed sha-256 certificates successfully and assigned them to accounts, and those accounts are no longer receiving IPN verifications. As a last resort, I substituted `https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/` for `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like this is nothing to do with SHA256, but a simple CN mismatch. A certificate is only good for the names listed in it. You could try adding a [subjectAltName](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName) for each of the required hosts, or a wildcard certificate for *.example.com (though I wouldn't trust one of those for my server.)

Comment: miken32, thanks for the reply. When you say 'wildcard certificate for *.example.com' do you mean literally '*.example.com', or if server has domain1.com and domain2.com, create one for '*.domain1.com' and '*.domain2.com'? As you can probably tell, I really don't know much about apache configuration, virtual hosts, etc.

Comment: Wildcard certificates work for sub domains, not multiple unrelated domains. If you have multiple unrelated domains, buy one for each domain or use subjectAltName. Whoever sold you your certificate should be able to explain all this to you and get you the correct cert for your needs.